# How to get this volume settings in android?

Tags: android, audio, settings, volume

[image]

when i click on button show the volume setting same the given pic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current volume of the device using the following:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```